# Numpy Delete cause Memory Leaks?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-leaks

In this piece of code I calculate some indices to delete from my array and even when doing so the memory in MB does not change at all. Is this a memory leak? I used `import os, psutil` for testing memory leaks. The array, `gen_next` is a numpy array of objects, in this case class objects

```
print("TOTAL MEMORY: " + str(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))

indices_replace = np.array(total[best_index:n, 1], dtype=int).tolist()

print("SIZE OF ARRAY BEFORE DELETE: " + str(sys.getsizeof(gen_next) ))

print("TOTAL MEMORY: " + str(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))

print("Length of indices_replace: " + str(len(indices_replace)))

print("Length of my array: " + str(len(gen_next)))

gen_next = np.delete(gen_next, indices_replace, axis=0)

print("SIZE OF ARRAY AFTER DELETE: " + str(sys.getsizeof(gen_next)))

print("Length after Deletion: " + str(len(gen_next)))

print("TOTAL MEMORY: " + str(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2))
```

Here is the output:

```
TOTAL MEMORY: 394.671875
SIZE OF ARRAY BEFORE DELETE: 136
TOTAL MEMORY: 394.671875
Length of indices_replace: 1
Length of my array: 10
SIZE OF ARRAY AFTER DELETE: 128
Length after Deletion: 9
TOTAL MEMORY: 394.6796875
```

So even though I delete an object from my array and reassign the array my memory goes up???

----- EDIT -----

I figured out that the numpy delete does not delete the objects when deleting them from the array, so the pointers are still out and about:

```
pointers = gen_next[indices_replace].tolist()
print("Pointers Before Deletion: " + str(pointers))
gen_next = np.delete(gen_next, indices_replace, axis=0)
print("Pointers After Deletion: " + str(pointers))
```

with output:

```
Pointers Before Deletion: [[<NeuroAutoEncoder.NeuroAutoEncoder.EvolvableNetwork object at 0x226A2B68>, <NeuroAutoEncoder.NeuroAutoEncoder.EvolvableNetwork object at 0x226A2B98>]]
Pointers After Deletion: [[<NeuroAutoEncoder.NeuroAutoEncoder.EvolvableNetwork object at 0x226A2B68>, <NeuroAutoEncoder.NeuroAutoEncoder.EvolvableNetwork object at 0x226A2B98>]]
```

so it seems that delete on numpy array of objects does not actually delete the array pointers

Comment: @roganjosh, do you know what the problem might be then? Each object in my array is about 30 MB so if was truly deleted the total amount of memory should be lower

Comment: what is `gen_next`? show a complete program.

Comment: @Daniel, can't really show that as its a list of a class object that is about 500 loc

Comment: It doesn't have to be the actual object you use, as long as what you show us is [minimal and complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Reti43, I figure out something so see updated question